# Does this opening gambit have a name?

Tags: opening, gambits

I have had some success with this gambit in blitz, does it have a name?

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 exd4 4. Ng5 h6 5. Nxf7 Kxf7 6. Bc4+ Ke8 7. Qh5+ Ke7 8. Qf7+ Kd6 9. Bf4+ Kc5 10. Qd5+ Kb6 11. Qb5#
```

Comment: I know its not directly related to the question, but Ng5 is really a bad move, however, your  opponent couldn't take advantage of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I think it is the "Silent-Tiger variation of the Scotch Gambit"!**

From Wikipedia:

> After 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 exd4, the most important continuations
>   are:
>
> - > 4.Nxd4 (Main line)
>   >
>   > - > 4...Bc5 (Classical Variation)
>   > - > 4...Nf6 (Schmidt Variation)
>   > - > 4...Qh4!? (Steinitz Variation)
>   > - > 4...Qf6
>   > - > 4...Nxd4?!
>   > - > 4...Bb4+?!
> - > 4.Bc4 (Scotch Gambit)
> - > 4.c3 (Göring Gambit)
> - > 4.Bb5

Answer (score 2):

"C45 : Scotch Game #3" according to the lichess.org

After `6. Bc4+` Black should have replied `6. ... d5` and win the game.

Comment: I though in the scotch game that move 4 is Bc4

Comment: @silent-tiger I'm not sure about the names, just copy-pasted to lichess -- it gives answers to many questions =)

Comment: @silent-tiger: that's the Scotch Gambit. Generally speaking 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 is the Scotch, the usual continuation is 3...exd4 4.Nxd4, 4.Bc4 is the Scotch Gambit, 4.c3 is the Goring Gambit. Your line with 4.Ng5? and 5.Nxf7? has no name.

Comment: Interestingly, 6...Kg6 (with the idea to hide on h7) seems to be equally winning according to Lichess' Stockfish. That and the boring 6...Ke7.